# Flutter PopupMenuButton - how to disable it conditionally

Tags: flutter

I have a simple `PopupMenuButton` implementation on `appTitle`. Here it is:

```
PopupMenuItem<int> _buildMenuItem(int size) {
  return PopupMenuItem<int>(
    value: size,
    child: Text('${size}x$size'),
  );
}

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Some title'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      PopupMenuButton<int>(
        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
        onSelected: _canReplay()
            ? (int size) {
                // do something with the size
              }
            : null,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<int>>[
              _buildMenuItem(3),
              _buildMenuItem(4),
              _buildMenuItem(5),
            ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: ...
);
```

UPDATED - I have realized my initial question might not be quite clear, so I rephrased it below:

What I would like to achieve is to disable `PopupMenuButton` based on app condition. Using the above code, I can enable / disable `onSelected` method invocation, however, icon appearance does not change.

To summarize - I would like the entire `PopupMenuButton` along with its icon to become disabled in the same fashion `IconButton` is disabled with you pass `null` to its `onPressed` method. That way, the user won't be able to even press the button and to invoke the menu.

Is that achievable?

Comment: could you put the code of your _buildMenuItem  ?

Comment: `buildMenuItem` code snippet added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few hours, I ended up with a following solution, which fits my requirements and it is implemented w/o any complex custom widgets. Here it is:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(allTranslations.text('Some title')),
    actions: <Widget>[
      _canReplay()
          ? PopupMenuButton<int>(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onSelected: (int size) {
                // do something with size
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<int>>[
                    _buildMenuItem(3),
                    _buildMenuItem(4),
                    _buildMenuItem(5),
                  ],
            )
          : IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
        onPressed: null,
            ),
    ],
  ),
  body: ...
);
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but can't completely hide for some bottom menu?

Comment: What do you mean by **completely hide from some bottom menu**? What would be the expected behavior?

Comment: I want to hide the specific menu Instead of keeping the refresh button for above mentioned case

Comment: I see, then replace `IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
        onPressed: null,
            )` in the above code with `Container()`. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `enabled` property of the `PopupMenuItem` widget.

```
  PopupMenuItem<int> _buildMenuItem(int size, bool enabled) {
    return PopupMenuItem<int>(
      value: size,
      child: Text('${size}x$size'),
      enabled: enabled,
    );
  }


      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<int>>[
        _buildMenuItem(3, true),
        _buildMenuItem(4, false),
        _buildMenuItem(5, true),
      ],
```

More info: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/PopupMenuItem/enabled.html

**UPDATE**

Based on the new information you give us about your question, it's not possible to disable the button using the `PopupMenuButton` button, but this is Flutter, so you can create your own Widget.

I created a custom `PopupMenuButton` where you can use the `enabled` property, take a look :

https://gist.github.com/diegoveloper/a388dd42a01ffff04cd51ec026381fe3

Usage:

```
    MyOwnPopupMenuButton<int>(
          enabled: _canReplay(),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.refresh,
            color: _canReplay() ? Colors.black : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
          ),
          onSelected: _canReplay()
              ? (int size) {
                  // do something with the size
                }
              : null,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<int>>[
                _buildMenuItem(3),
                _buildMenuItem(4),
                _buildMenuItem(5),
              ],
        )
```

Comment: I realized my question might not be quite clear, hence I have updated it. Anyway - your suggestion above won't work since I need to disable the entire popup menu along with its icon. Your suggestion will disable specific menu item, however the menu itself can still open, which is not the desirable result.

Comment: Nope it won't work - this will change icon **color**, however, the icon is still **clickable**, hence the user can click it and open the menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the button (so that pressing on it does not show the menu, but still the icon), you can use the `enabled` property of `PopupMenuButton`

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
  enabled: _canReplay(),
  icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
  onSelected: (int size) {
    // do something with size
  },
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<int>>[
    _buildMenuItem(3),
    _buildMenuItem(4),
    _buildMenuItem(5),
  ],
)
```

I hope that I understood correctly :D